# Does the current HotSpot JVM run in parallel by default?

Tags: jvm, java, jvm-hotspot

I'm using this Java version:

```
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.3) (suse-9.1-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

When I start a java program, e.g.

```
java TestApp
```

by default, will the JVM run in parallel ?

If so, which parts run in parallel ?

I am interested in this, because I found if I use `taskset -c 0 java TestApp` to bind `TestApp` running on `processor 0`, the first running time is much slower than `java TestApp`. Does this imply something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of single threaded tasks which have a thread of their own.

- the main thread which runs you program
- the background byte code to native compiler
- the finalizer thread (to call finalize() on objects)
- the GC thread pool

Your code will only use as many threads as you create (plus "main" which created for you)

Answer (score 1):

The JVM has native threads and no Global Lock, if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The first running time is probably largely JITing the bytecode to machine code. I would suspect very strongly that process is optimized for parallel scenarios.

Comment: That's interesting. Then the question becomes how does JIT run in parallel by default?

Comment: The JIT is a platform native application. I'm sure it would not be unreasonable to detect the number of CPUs and act accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, my question was which parts of JIT run in parallel?

Comment: No. That is not how JIT works. The output of the JIT compiler is not saved between runs. What you are seeing is almost certainly the cold start effect of the first time that the JVMs shared libraries are being touched.